# How restore the old search function (C-f)?

Tags: vimperator

I like the standard Firefox search better the the Vimperator's search. So I want it back and unmap or remap the current (page down) C-f shortcut. I already tried `:nunmap <C-f>` but it didn't worked.

Is there a way to get back the old search box? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've expanded my answer. Would be cool to know what you find better in FF search. It really piqued my interest.

Answer (score 4):

Edited more in line with the actual question. Apology for being slow with the edit, but I am slightly surprised why do you want a search that ain't as easy for keyboard as <kbd>/</kbd> is. :-) If you could explain, would be really good to know. :-)

### When FF shortcut works without mapping

Playing with search today I realized that pressing <kbd>/</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> launches default search. So, in Search mode you can launch the FF Search.

### Mapping doesn't work?

Per Vimperator's help on mappings, these won't work *between* sessions **unless** you put them in your `.rc` file.

Also, try just 
`unmap <C-f>`
Your version is for Normal mode, perhaps that is why it didn't work? When I unmapped <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

### Defining your own command

Finally, there's the `command` option:
`command -description="Firefox search" -nargs=0 ffs emenu Edit.Find`

This allows you to call FF search without mappings. Haven't tested if it needs to be persisted between sessions like the mappings do.

#### Problems with FF Search

I don't know how to close it "mouselessly", other than to continue to hit tab till you get to closing 'x' button.
I can do search next, but can't do search previous (no Edit > Search > Previous).

#### Workaround - more keys than other options

How about <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>? And when you're done, <kbd>Insert</kbd> again? This is pass-through mode, which passes your keys straight to Firefox. No remapping is required then.